# Confusion understanding a half adder implementation using 74153 MUX

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, analysis

As shown [here,](https://sjce.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/DEC-LAB-Manual-1st-Aug-2017.pdf) I have also highlighted the confusing part in the attached snapshot.

In the last line of truth table, I know that sum is equal to XOR of two inputs, but here in the last line of the truth table, the selected input pins are highlighted and they will be I1a (having a 0 value on it) and I1b (having a 1 value on it.) If we XOR 1 with 0, we should get 1 in sum column, but there is a 0 in the truth table.

Why?

Is this circuit correct?

[image]

Comment: there's two outputs. Your "XOR" only describes one of them. What's the question, then?

Comment: Sum = A XOR B, (1 XOR 1 = 0), C = A AND B (1 AND 1 = 1). The truth table is correct. What is the problem?

Comment: If we XOR 1 with 0, we should get 1 in sum column as the scenario is here in case of "1"at both A and B, IC data pins I1a and I1b will be selected which have values 0 and 1on them respectively,but here 0 is written in truth table,which is not XOR of 1 with 0

Comment: But last line of truth table is 11, which is 0 for S or an XOR for all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last row, the XOR is done between A and B, not I1a (= not A) and S0.

---

Let's make a truth table.

The multiplexer is used just as dual 2-input, as S1 is always 0. So we need only to consider I0a, I1a, I0b, and I1b together with S0.

| A | B | I0a = A | I1a = not A | I0b = 0 | I1b = A | S0 = B | Sum = Ya | Carry = Yb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | ### 0 | 1 | ### 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | ### 1 | 0 | ### 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | ### 1 | 0 | ### 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | ### 0 | 0 | ### 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Looks correct for me. ;-)